# How can I programmatically start a program in the 32 bits or 64 bits environment?

Tags: macos, executable

I have a binary that can be run in both 32 and 64 bits, that loads dynamic bundles for fiddling purposes. However, by default it runs on the 64 bits environment; so if I hit a 32-bits only bundle, `dlopen` fails.

It's easy to check for this beforehand, so all I really need is a way to choose whether to launch it in 32 bits or 64 bits. How can I programmatically do that? I'm open to anything Snow Leopard might support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what @GWW wrote, if you really want to do this programmatically, you can use [posix_spawnattr_setbinpref_np](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/posix_spawnattr_setbinpref_np.3.html) to set the preferred CPU type and then use [posix_spawn](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/posix_spawn.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/posix_spawn).

The CPU type is specified by `cpu_type_t`, which I believe is defined in `#include <mach/machine.h>`. But it may be safer to include `#include <mach-o/arch.h>`.  See [arch (3) manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arch.3.html).

Comment: It's defined with `<mach-o/fat.h>` (somewhere in the `#include` graph), and I already include it.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me to launch python in 32-bit / 64-bit

```
arch -i386 python
Python 2.7 (r27:82500, Nov 10 2010, 22:46:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxint
2147483647

arch -x86_64 python
Python 2.7 (r27:82500, Nov 10 2010, 22:46:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxint
9223372036854775807
```