# Jar bundler -d32 vm arguments

Tags: macos, jvm-arguments, jarbundler

I have created an application which uses 32bit libraries on my 64bit Mac Lion so to run my application I need to pass -d32 vm argument in eclipse and it works fine. I created runnable jar of application and it also works fine when I run jar from terminal with -d32 vm arguments but the problem comes when I creates .app file of my application using jar bundler. I passed -d32 in vm options textbox of jar bundler but when I run .app the application icon comes up in dock but application window does not show up.

I think it is vm argument issue but I am not sure about it. I was wondering if there is some other way to pass vm arguments in jar bundler.

Any suggestions related to this problem are welcome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way of doing this through the Jar Bundler app, but their is a solution.

Create the `.app` as usual using Jar Bundler. Right click and "Get Info" on the newly-created application, check the "Open in 32-bit mode" box.

Setting this flag programatically [seems to be tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064450/forcing-a-cocoa-application-to-start-in-32-bit-mode-programatically) but possible.

Comment: Then it's something in your app. If you can run your `jar` without problems using `java -d32 jar your-jar-file.jar`, then this method should work. You can run the program in a terminal by going to `MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS` and double-clicking the `JavaApplicationStub`. You'll see any error messages in the Terminal window that opens.